# Storing session in database with CakePHP 2.0

Tags: database, session, cakephp-2.0

I'm using CakePHP 2.0, and tries to configure it to store sessions in a database.

However, I find the [official documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html) very unclear. I understand I need to set the following in core.php:

```
<?php
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'database',
    'handler' => array(
        'model' => 'CustomSession'
    )
));
```

I've created the table with cake's schema:

```
CREATE TABLE cake_sessions (
  id varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  data text,
  expires int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
);
```

It still doesn't work. Do I need to create the session model by myself? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have created the model in the core file as cake_sessions, you will need to name your table as cake_sessions. cake_session is the default model

```
<?php
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'database',
    'handler' => array(
        'model' => 'cake_sessions'
    )
));
```